# What are the upstart events to monitor to attach/detach an EBS volume and an elastic IP at startup/shutdown?

Tags: upstart, cloud, amazon-ec2

I'm setting up an Ubuntu instance on Amazon EC2 and I'm trying to configure it so that, at startup, it automatically attaches an EBS volume and takes an elastic IP address and, at shutdown, it automatically releases those resources.

I found various init scripts that do what I want, but I'd really like to use an upstart job, so that I can automatically install it through cloud-init.

I understand from [this exchange](http://groups.google.com/group/ec2ubuntu/browse_thread/thread/3a0ccf40a45e7857) that the event I want to monitor to start my job is, for lucid and maverick

```
start on stopped cloud-run-user-script
```

and for natty

```
start on stopped cloud-final
```

Is this really accurate? Also, what is the correct event to monitor to stop my job (including unmounting and detaching the EBS volume and releasing the elastic IP)?

Comment: `start on stopped cloud-final` still works on `saucy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The events are correct if you specifically need to run when cloud-init has finished. You probably will want your script to be done with the keyword `task`, so that the bits that depend on cloud-init are blocked until your script finishes.

For shutdown

```
start on runlevel [016]
```

Will run something as the normal system shutdown is happening.

Note that there's a wealth of information about these things in the upstart cookbook:

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice the cookbook in my searches...