# How can I monitor cloud-init for errors, and trigger a script when it fails?

Tags: 12.04, amazon-ec2, cloud-init

I'm using `cloud-init` to provision servers in AWS, and would like my servers to send an email when they're done (whether they fail or succeed). For successful cloud-init runs, the solution is trivial. `cloud-init` has a built-in module for this kind of thing. From the [the source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cloud-init-dev/cloud-init/trunk/view/head:/doc/examples/cloud-config.txt):

```
# When cloud-init is finished running including having run 
# cloud_init_modules, then it will run this command.  The default
# is to emit an upstart signal as shown below.  If the value is a
# list, it will be passed to Popen.  If it is a string, it will be
# invoked through 'sh -c'.
# 
# default value:
# cc_ready_cmd: [ initctl, emit, cloud-config, CLOUD_CFG=/var/lib/instance//cloud-config.txt ]
# example:
# cc_ready_cmd: [ sh, -c, 'echo HI MOM > /tmp/file' ]
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work when a cloud-init script fails. Another [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40881/what-are-the-upstart-events-to-monitor-to-attach-detach-an-ebs-volume-and-an-ela) seems to suggest I could monitor `upstart` for success, but again, it doesn't appear to work for failure. The following upstart job, for example, executes both on success and failure:

```
start on stopped cloud-final
script
    echo "cloud-final stopped" > /tmp/cloud
end script
```

Can I monitor cloud-init for failure and trigger a script when it exits? If so, how could I do it? I'm using ubuntu v12.04.

Answer (score 1):

12.04 is out of support.  There isn't a great answer for cloud-init in that version.

In newer versions of cloud-init, cloud-init writes `/run/cloud-init/result.json` with content like:

```
{
 "v1": {
  "datasource": "DataSourceNoCloud [seed=/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net][dsmode=net]",
  "errors": []
 }
}
```

If there are errors, it will have non-empty value in the `errors` list.

Also, as cloud-init runs it maintains `/run/cloud-init/status.json`.

In 17.2, there is a sub-command that can help.  `cloud-init status --wait` will allow your custom scripts to block until cloud-init is done.  If cloud-init had errors, then status will exit non-zero. (Thanks to Chad Smith for this suggestion).

```
$ cat > /usr/local/bin/after-cloud-init <<"EOF"
#!/bin/bash
# Block until cloud-init completes
exec >/run/after-cloud-init.txt 2>&1
msg() { read up idle < /proc/uptime; echo "$up:" "$@"; }
msg starting
if ! cloud-init status --wait ; then
    msg "Cloud-init failed with $?"
    exit 1
fi
msg done. put your stuff here.
exit 1
EOF

$ chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/after-cloud-init
$ crontab -e 
@reboot /usr/local/bin/after-cloud-init
$ sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, cloud-init 17.2 added a new sub-command that can help:

**cloud-init status --wait** will allow your custom scripts to block until cloud-init is done.

A cloud-init error will exit non-zero and your script could react to that.

Here's a simple cron script and entry runs on each boot that would do it for someone (presuming cloud-init 17.2+)

```
$ cat > /home/ubuntu/yourscript.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
set -e
cloud-init status --wait  > /dev/null 2>&1 # Blocks until cloud-init 
completes
echo 'Cloud-init now done ' `date -R`  # do things here
EOF
$ chmod 755 /home/ubuntu/yourscript.sh
$  crontab -e 
@reboot /home/ubuntu/yourscript.sh
$ sudo reboot
```

Comment: I have a situation when `cloud-init status` returns an error and non-zero exit status but `/run/cloud-init/status.json` returns no errors. And the host is working as expected.